# Simple angular service has no context (this = undefined) when deployed to heroku?

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment

So I have a simple service that is being injected one place in my entire angular project:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}

getData() {
return this.http.get('/Data').map((data) => {
  return data;
})
}
}
```

I have one component that's importing this service and injecting it in the constructor. The NgOnInit makes one subscription to the service:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
  this.data= data;
});
}
```

This is all running fine locally. I'm able to use this subscription to get data back and show it on my front-end. The problem arises when I deploy to Heroku. Once deployed to heroku (successfully), when I set a breakpoint in the service itself inside the getData method (first block of code above), keyword this is undefined. When I run heroku logs -t there's nothing to suggest any error, because this was undefined and the http request never gets sent. I know the backend is running successfully on heroku because if I navigate to myProjectUrl/Data, all of the data is there.

How can I debug this further? I'm stumped as to why it only works locally, but have no real error message to go off of.

Comment: What does your bootstrap array look like in the main app?

Comment: which versions you use ? of rxjs angular ?